# Trying to combining generics and operator overloading in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, operator-overloading

The following does not work, I imagine my intent is readable from the code. I was unable to find examples or documentation if it is possible.

```
type
  TV2<T> = record
    X: T;
    Y: T;
    class operator add(a,b: TV2<T>): TV2<T>;

  end;

TV2S = TV2<Single>;
TV2I = TV2<Int64>;


implementation

class operator TV2<T>.add(a, b: TV2<T>): TV2<T>;
begin

  Result.X := a.X + b.X; // I'm getting "E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type"
  Result.Y := a.Y + b.Y; // I'm getting "E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type"

end;
```

Comment: Suppose I need somesort of TNumeric

Comment: Generic capabilities must be known beforehand. Not every type has operators, so there is no way to define a generic unconstrained type with them.